# How to use PIL to save as an ICO image with 32*32 or 64*64

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I make a tool to transform the format of a picture.

Now the question is that,
What should I do if I want to transform a picture(.png or .jpg) to ico (32*32) or even (64*64)?

if I use this code

```
img.save("pic.ico")
```

It will just only generate a ico(16*16).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the various sizes are embedded in the single output file, see [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#ico).

You can check with **ImageMagick** in Terminal:

```
identify a.ico
a.ico[0] PNG 16x16 16x16+0+0 8-bit sRGB 118B 0.000u 0:00.001
a.ico[1] PNG 24x24 24x24+0+0 8-bit sRGB 129B 0.000u 0:00.000
a.ico[2] PNG 32x32 32x32+0+0 8-bit sRGB 146B 0.000u 0:00.000
a.ico[3] PNG 48x48 48x48+0+0 8-bit sRGB 195B 0.000u 0:00.000
a.ico[4] PNG 64x64 64x64+0+0 8-bit sRGB 242B 0.000u 0:00.000
a.ico[5] PNG 128x128 128x128+0+0 8-bit sRGB 484B 0.000u 0:00.000
a.ico[6] PNG 256x256 256x256+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2459B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Failing that, you may have reduced your image dimensions to 16x16 and it won't enlarge that to make the bigger versions. You need to pass an image that is as big as the largest icon you want to make.